# SQL in booking system C#

Tags: c#, sql

In my booking system I have three tables: tbl_times with all the times. tbl_client with all the clients and tbl_app with all the booked appointments.

I want to write SQL to display ALL the times from tbl_times together with the clients names for the times that are booked for a certain doctor on a certain date.

**Is it even possible to do this?** See picture for what I want to display (the yellow appointment times).[image]

I have this code now, but it displays the times that are booked and not all the times.

```
conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT tbl_app.time, tbl_client.clientname FROM tbl_app, tbl_client WHERE tbl_app.date = '2014-05-05' AND tbl_app.drId = '4' AND tbl_client.clientId = tbl_app.clientId";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);   
ds.Reset(); 
da.Fill(ds);   
dt = ds.Tables[0]; 
GridView1.DataSource = dt;              
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: `tbl_times` and `tbl_app` both share a time column `times` and `time` respectively. Are the row values in those two columns identical? If so, you probably don't need `tbl_times` and can probably `JOIN` `tbl_app` on `tbl_client` `ON` `clientId`.

Comment: I need tbl_times for other purposes, so I want to keep it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
select t.times,
ISNULL(tc.clientname,'') as clientname
from tbl_times t
left join tbl_app ta
on t.times = ta.times
and ta.date = '2014-05-05' AND ta.drId = '4'
left join tbl_client tc
on ta.clientid = tc.clientid
```

Comment: He wants *all* times, not just booked times.  You need a `LEFT JOIN` so the times in `tbl_app` don't filter out records.

Comment: @Ek0nomik, that's correct indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I've tried you code but it displays all the booked appointments. I only want the appointments for a certain date and a certain doctor, together with ALL the times

Comment: @user2939293 Including the criteria in the `left join` criteria as Rahul has done now, is the only right way. If included in the `where`, the times without appointment would still be filtered out.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, but your SQL now displays the same exact thing as my SQL does.

Comment: @Rahul, the join on tbl_client should be left join as well

Comment: @user2939293, same thing means "Wrong result"? are you sure though? cause conceptually my query should give you the exact result as you have posted.

Comment: @Rahul, yes the wrong output. Your (and mine) SQL shows only the yellow rows. I want to show ALL the times together with the names of the clients in the appointments. The rest is left empty. (See the last table for my desired output).

Comment: @user2939293, would you mind trying again. see edited answer. Thanks to ME.Name

Comment: Changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, as @Me.Name suggested made it!
Thank you guys for you help! You did it!

Comment: @Me.Name, cool buddy; not sure how did I missed it. appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You want to

```
LEFT join tbl_times
```

A LEFT join will return all rows from the left table.

You should reconsider having a table with 1 column though

EDIT:

Consider adding an ID to the times for easier SQL/Syntax

timeID|times
0     |08:00
1     |08:30
2     |09:00

etc

Comment: Thank you, but I need the table tbl_times for other purposes, even thought it only has one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.times time, c.clientname FROM tbl_times t
LEFT JOIN tbl_app a ON a.time = t.times
LEFT JOIN tbl_client c ON c.clientid = a.clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
SELECT a.time, c.clientname
FROM tbl_times t
LEFT JOIN tbl_app a on t.time = t.time
JOIN tbl_client c on a.clientid = c.clientid
WHERE a.drID = 4 and a.date = '2014-05-05'
```

EDIT: The above code doesn't work.  The code below does work and it uses a sub-query.  This might be a good approach if your selection criteria gets more complicated.

```
select t.[time], ISNULL( c.clientname, '') as clientname from
tbl_times t
left join (select * from tbl_app where drID = 4 and [date] = '2014-05-05') 
as doc on t.time = doc.[time]
left join tbl_client c on doc.clientID = c.clientID
```

Comment: Nope, this gives the same exact output as my SQL. Thanks anyway!